# Exposing the underlying type of an opaque

Tags: swift, generics, opaque-types

I am trying to have a deeper understanding of the difference between a generic type and an opaque type. The one thing that is clear about opaque type is that the compiler does not expose the underlying type. I wanted to check it and ran this little code:

```
func exposeGeneric<T: Equatable>(t: T) {
    print(type(of: t))
}

func exposeOpaque(t: some Equatable) {
    print(type(of: t))
}

func returnOpaque() -> some Equatable {
    2
}

exposeGeneric(t: "asdf")
exposeOpaque(t: 1)
print(type(of: returnOpaque()))
```

And the output was

```
String
Int
Int
```

What is the difference then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type(of:)` returns the underlying runtime type of the value, including if the value is in an existential container (such as an `any` container). As you note, `some` types are hidden from you by the compiler (the compiler knows what they are, but does not expose it to calling code). But the type can still be interrogated at runtime.

### Generics

```
func exposeGeneric<T: Equatable>(t: T)
...
exposeGeneric(t: "asdf")
```

At compile-time, this creates a new, specialized function:

```
func exposeGeneric(t: String)
```

This function is then called, exactly as if it took `String` as its parameter. This can lead to copying the entire function multiple times if there are many different callers with different types. (There are some optimizations to reduce the actual copying, but in principle, that's what's happening.)

This tool lets you write generic code, applying algorithms to types that conform to a set of requirements (i.e. a protocol).

### `some` parameter types

```
func exposeOpaque(t: some Equatable)
...
exposeOpaque(t: 1)
```

This is not an opaque type. This is just a more friendly syntax for the first example. It works exactly the same; you just don't have to define a type parameter (`T`). This syntax is preferred when possible because it's a bit easier to read.

This tool is just to make it nicer to write generic code.

### Opaque Return Values

```
func returnOpaque() -> some Equatable
...
let x = returnOpaque()
```

This is an [opaque type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/opaquetypes/). The compile-time type of `x` here is "the return type of `returnOpaque(), which is known to be Equatable." That is all you know about this type at compile-time. It is a **specific** type (in this case Int), and the compiler knows what it is, but the caller does not.

It is known to be the same type every time you call `returnOpaque()`, so this is valid:

```
returnOpaque() == returnOpaque()
```

But this is not:

```
func returnOpaque() -> some Equatable { 2 }
func otherReturnOpaque() -> some Equatable { 2 }

returnOpaque() == otherReturnOpaque() // Invalid. Type-mismatch
```

The left-hand type is "the return type of `returnOpaque`" and the right-hand type is "the return type of `otherReturnOpaque`". Those are not the same nominal type, even though they are the same structural type (i.e. they both resolve to Int).

This tool lets you hide implementation details in cases where the returned type may be complex or implementation dependent. For example, consider:

```
func f<T>(_ array: [T]) -> some Collection<T> {
    array.reversed()
}
```

This returns a `ReversedCollection<T>`, which makes the caller dependent on the implementation detail. If I rewrote this as:

```
func f<T>(_ array: [T]) -> some Collection<T> {
    var array = array
    array.reverse()
    return array
}
```

then the returned type would change to `[T]`. With an opaque return type, the caller doesn't have to change anything. It's still "type type returned by `f()` specialized with the type parameter `T`."

In the past, we might have used something like `AnyCollection<T>` to deal with this, but that has performance impacts, both in making copies and in preventing some inlining optimizations. `some Collection<T>` gets the advantages of hiding the type information without the cost of wrapping it in a type eraser. (See `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` for a classic example of this in Combine.)

### Existentials

Just to throw one more example into the mix:

```
func exposeExistential(t: any Equatable) {
    print(type(of: t))
}

exposeExistential(t: 1)  // prints "Int"
```

This function takes a value that conforms to Equatable and wraps it into an existential container. This container has a different memory layout, and may require heap allocations. The function than operates on the existential container, which forwards methods to the wrapped value.

This is slower, but in some cases can be more flexible. For example, if you had many types that all conform to some protocol, you could put them all in an Array of type `[any MyProtocol]`. You can't do that with generics, because the Array needs to be of a single type. `[some MyProtocol]` would have to be all Ints or all Strings for example (assuming Int and String conform.)

When possible, avoid `any` types. They are expensive and have some surprising corner cases (though fewer in recent versions of Swift). But in cases where you really need a heterogeneous Collection, they're available.

As an example of a corner case that still exists, consider:

```
func f(_ p: [some P]) {}

func g(_ p: any P) {
    f([p])  // Error: Type 'any P' cannot conform to 'P'
}
```

Existentials do not conform to the protocol they wrap. `any P` does not itself conform to `P`. This can bite you at surprising times, especially since Swift has added features (called "opening") to make this "just work anyway" in some simple cases. So you can get a long way down the road and suddenly discover that you're stuck and need to redesign. If you do need to use `any` types, try to keep their usage simple to avoid these surprises.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Opaque return types is to expose concrete type information to the compiler, while intentionally *hiding* it from the user. A library (like SwiftUI) can leverage this to return very large, complex generic types while hiding those from the user. This has two benefits:

1. The user's code can't call anything on the result that isn't described by the protocol. This gives the library author the freedom to change the specific type they return, so long as it implements the protocol they promised.
2. The compiler can keep the full type information, and use it for the benefit of optimizations that would be lost with something like `AnyView`.

Here's an example to walk through the difference:

```swift
protocol Shape { // Not a great protocol, but it's a simple example.
    func area() -> Double
}

struct Square: Shape {
    let sideLength: Double
    
    func area() -> Double { sideLength * sideLength }
}

func returnsOpaqueShape() -> some Shape {
    // The implementation knows it always returns a Square.
    return Square(sideLength: 2)
}

let opaqueShape = returnsOpaqueShape()
// The caller knows it's some kind of Shape, so it can do Shape-y things on it:
print(opaqueShape.area())
// But we can't treat it like a Square, even though it is (opaquely) a Square.
// The library wants its exposed contract to be `some Shape`, and the fact
// that it's actually `Square` is an implementation detail.
// The compiler would actually know that this call is _possible_,
// but _intentionally_ restricts you, to ensure you don't accidentally depend
// on that implementation detail. Thus the library author would be free to return
// a `Circle` instead, knowing that no calling code could break as a result.
print(opaqueShape.sideLength) // ❌ value of type 'some Shape' has no member 'sideLength'

func returnsAGenericShape<S: Shape>(shape: S) -> S {
    // The implementation knows it always returns the same S that came in
    // *and* the type system communicates exactly what the result S will be.
    return shape
}

// Notice that the caller knows the result is a Square (not merely `some Shape`)
let nonOpaqueShape: Square = returnsAGenericShape(shape: Square(sideLength: 2))

// So it can treat it like a Square:
print(nonOpaqueShape.sideLength) // ✅ compiles and runs fine
```